# Error loading a function for my Navigator in React Native, told it's a render method issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, components, stack-navigator, react-native-tabnavigator

[This is the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN77C.png)

[This is my BottomTabNavigator:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGCNB.png)

[This is my RootStack:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QGfe.png)

Been scratching my head on this one all day. I'm not sure how I
should approach it. Any help or guidance would be immensely appreciated

Comment: Can you show the full image of BottomTabNavigator? also full error message, I have posted the possible fix. try that

Comment: Please post actual code than images of the code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/7337506

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is one issue when you are trying to create a Bottom Tab Navigator

Change **createBottomTabNavigator** to **createBottomTabNavigator()**

refer to the code change below

```
// Your Code
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator;

// Correct
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
```